# Running Django Management command in crontab

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run the management command `python manage.py process_tasks` provided by Django background tasks to run my background tasks. I want to run them as a cronjob.

To do this I am creating a entry in cron tab using the command `sudo crontab -e`

My crontab entry looks something like this -

`*/1 * * * * . /var/www/cronjob.sh >> /var/www/crontab.log 2>&1`

and the contents of the shell script which I am running here are -

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
 echo 'starting'
 sudo su ubuntu
 . /var/www/myproject/env/bin/activate
 . /var/www/myproject/.shahrukh_aliases
 python /var/www/myproject/src/manage.py process_tasks
 echo 'finished'
 sleep 2
done
```

But the problem is that my EC2 instance crashes after some time and runs only after I restart it. I get the following error

`-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory`

I think it's consuming all the memory and hence my instance crashes. I don't know how to run the task in cron job and why it is consuming my memory. I want to know how can I run this job as a cronjob.
Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: while is always true so this process never ends..

Comment: I need to run every 2 second, that&#39;s why I used a loop, what should I do in that case?

Comment: but you start it every minute. And each takes forever. Cronjob is not the way to go here. If you need to run some background process like this, better use celery or similar.

Comment: Celery will be too advanced for my use case, is there some other way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was simple. I can still do it using crontab. I just had to provide an extra parameter to the process_tasks command.

So my command which I have to run from crontab is

```
python manage.py process_tasks --duration 59
```

since I am running the job after every minute and the above command will run background tasks for 59 seconds and then end itself which will then be restarted by cron.